# Use init container for running commands in the actual pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I need to install some libraries in my pod before it starts working as expected.

My use case: I need some libraries that will support SMB (samba), and the image that I have to use does not have it installed.

Unfortunately, exec'ing into the actual pod and running commands do not seem to be a very good idea.

Is there a way by which I can use an init-container to install `libsmbclient-dev` in my ubuntu pod?

Edit: Some restrictions in my case.

1. I use helm chart to install my app (nextcloud). So I guess I cannot use a custom image (as far as I know, we cannot use our own images in an existing helm chart). This would have been the best solution.
2. I cannot run commands in kubernetes value.yaml since I do not use `kubectl` to install my app. Also I need to restart apache2 after I install the library, and unfortunately, restarting apache2 results in restarting the pod, effectively making the whole installation meaningless.

Since nextcloud helm allows the use of initcontainers, I wondered if that could be used, but as far as I understand the usability of initcontainers, this is not possible (?).

Answer (score 3):

You should build your own container image - e.g. with docker - and push it to a container repository that is suitable for your cluster, e.g. Docker Hub, AWS ECR, Google Artifact registry ...

First install docker (https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/)

create an empty directory and change into it.
Then create a file `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsmbclient-dev \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Execute

`docker build -t myimage:latest .`

This will download Ubuntu and build a new container image where the commands from the `RUN` statement will be executed. The image name will be `myimage` and the version will be `latest`.

Then push your image with `docker push` to your appropriate repository.

See also Docker best practices:
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the most suitable solution, and that's what I do currently. But since I have used a helm chart to install my kubernetes cluster, I also had to make my own local helm chart so that I can use my own custom image. I couldn't find a good way to use my own image in an existing helm chart.

Comment: depending on the chart, you may have the option to override the image